# Creating image with hyperlink using google-apps-script

Tags: image, hyperlink, google-apps-script

I have been trying to put an image with a hyperlink on it into a google apps script ui. I first thought of using createAnchor(), but that only allows text. Then I thought of using a button, but as far as I know you cannot open a new tab/window and redirect in a callback function.

I also tried createHTML(), but the  element is not handled by it as yet.

I have seen people overlay transparent buttons over images, but still have same issue in callback.

My research has not found an answer to this. Does anyone have any solutions/examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Chrome20 and IE9

```
      // Container for box and results
      var imageContainer = app.createFlexTable();


      // Setup the button
      var button = app.createButton("ImageButton");
      button.setStyleAttribute("background", "url(dontshowimagehere.JPG) no-repeat");
      button.setStyleAttribute("position", "absolute");
      button.setStyleAttribute("color", "transparent");
      button.setStyleAttribute('zIndex','1');
      button.setStyleAttribute("border", "0px solid black");



      imageContainer.setWidget(0, 0, button);

      // image to click
      var image = app.createImage("image.jpg").setId(imageId);

      imageContainer.setWidget(1,0, image);
```

The image has a slight (3px) offset. If important, this looks to fix it http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp (use relative for the flex table and top etc for the image and button)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a transparent Anchor overlaying the image?

```
function doGet() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Image Anchor");
var panel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setWidth('50%').setHeight('50%');
var image = app.createImage().setUrl("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-v0Q3gPQz03Q/T_y5gcVw7LI/AAAAAAAAAF8/ol9uup7Xm2g/s512/GooglePlus-512-Red.png").setStyleAttribute("width", "28px").setStyleAttribute("height", "28px");
var anchor = app.createAnchor("?", "https://plus.google.com/u/1/116085534841818923812/posts").setHeight("28px").setWidth("28px").setStyleAttribute("opacity", "0.1").setTarget("blank");
panel.add(image,100,50);
panel.add(anchor,100,50);
app.add(panel);  
return app.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> app.createAbsolutePanel()
>   .add(app.createImage('https://www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png'))
>   .add(app.createAnchor('','https://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/about/')
>   .setStyleAttributes({position:'absolute',top:'0px',left:'0px',width:'201px',height:'47px',opacity:'0'}))

This is a tested one. It works fine.
It doesn't work with positioning the image (as 'absolute').
It doesn't work with .setHorizontalAlignment(UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with the widgets available. I would suggest altering your UI's design to utilize an Anchor widget instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML Box if you are coding directly on your page. Click "Edit" to edit your page and go to "Insert>HTML Box" in your menu. It will accept javascript too! There are a few caveats - when using javascript, HTML Box will not accept links...too bad, but too many exploits there.

If you are coding in apps script, you could try to place the image on a panel and use absolute panel and position your link over your image. Another method could be to use the .setStyleAttribute for CSS styling and utilize the zIndex parameter to place a panel over top of your image....like so:

```
var panel = app.createSimplePanel();
// add your image to the simple panel or whatever panel you wish to choose in your GUI

var popPanel = app.createSimplePanel()
  .setStyleAttribute('top','Y')
  .setStyleAttribute('left','X')
  .setStyleAttribute('zIndex','1')
  .setStyleAttribute('position','fixed');
// add your anchor to the popPanel

app.add(panel).add(popPanel);
```

Not 100% sure if you can make this panel transparent, but you could try something like:
    .setStyleAttribute('background',transparent') 
or change the opacity via:
    .setStyleAttribute('opacity','.5')

Hopes this gives you a few ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with a single Anchor object and using CSS3.
It works on Chrome, I did not test it in other Browsers.

```
gui.createAnchor("", false, "$DESTINATION_URL$")
   .setStyleAttributes({ "display":"block",
                         "width":"$IMAGE_WIDTH_IN_PIXEL$",
                         "height":"$IMAGE_HEIGHT_IN_PIXEL$",
                         "background":"url($URL_OF_THE_IMAGE$)",
                         "background-size":"100% 100%",
                         "background-repeat":"no-repeat" })
```

Of course you have to replace the $......$ with your data.

Thierry

Answer (score -1):

If you first create all your HTML in a string, you can then replace the content of a page with the HTML you want like this:

```
var myString = 'the html you want to add, for example you image link and button';
var page = SitesApp.getSite('example.com', 'mysite').getChildByName('targetpage');
var upage = page.setHtmlContent('<div>' + myString + '</div>');
```

Comment: The HTML widget doesn't support links or images.

Comment: button.setStyleAttribute("background", "url(image.JPG) no-repeat"); works on chrome, but does not show on IE. But even with this issue, it does get past the click problem of transparent IE buttons.